# How to write a datatable to excel work book at client side

Tags: visual-studio

Currently i am doing one project in that we need to generate report from database.
 Since my server memory is too low im getting 'Out of Memory' Exception when im writing it at serverside and also when i write directly to a excel file using http header as excel file im not able to create multiple sheets since my database table is huge more than 65536 rows.
I saw many solution using a third party tool but i cant use those into mine..If anyone already worked on this please give me some direction.
Also i tried using javascript but for that i need to use datagrid at server side??
but in my project i m not allowed to use like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can open an excel file, as an xml document using the Open XML format SDK: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx